# PostgreSQL : Need help for Loop with conditions

Tags: postgresql

i don't know if it's possible but i have a big table with many entries and i want to factorize it.

This table is named `Listen`, it saves the time people are listening a stream and it works this way:

if someone is listening we create a new entry every 30 sec with the value listening_time n-1 + 30.
So if someone is listening 120 sec i have 4 entries (i factorize it and now it's creating only one entry for that but i have all the old entries).

what i'm looking to do is something like that:

```
select * 
from listen 
order by session_id asc, id asc
```

- 1st entry is saved
- 2d entry: if (listening_time(n) = listening_time((n-1)+30) update last entry
  else new entry.

i don't know how to do the if, else for that n and n-1 but i know how to update the entry.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a `select` query that returns that data or for an `update` statement that actually changes the data? Also some sample data with the expected outcome will be helpful.

Comment: i try to update the table for have less entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to record when someone starts listening and then update every 30 seconds if the listening session is still on. If that is correct and you can alter the table structure I would add a column that records the `last_ping` (or some other useful name) in addition to the listening start time. Every listening session will then have a single record in your table.

You can make this happen automatically using an `INSERT` trigger as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION listening () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Try to update an existing session, set the last_ping column to the time provided.
  UPDATE listen SET last_ping = NEW.listening_time
  WHERE session_id = NEW.session_id
  AND id = NEW.id
  AND last_ping > NEW.listening_time - 30 seconds;

  -- If that worked, cancel the insert operation. Otherwise, the session is new or there
  -- is a new listening period so insert a new record, with last_ping set to listening_time.
  IF FOUND THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  ELSE
    NEW.last_ping := NEW.listening_time;
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_listen
  BEFORE INSERT ON listen
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE listening();
```

The trick here is to try to insert a record with session_id, id and listening_time. Inside the trigger - before the insert actually takes place - an attempt is made to update an existing listening session which, if successful, updates the last_ping time and make the insert fail (by returning NULL). If there is no current session to update, then let the insert proceed (by returning NEW).